# Where do I find the definition of Rf_protect() in R's sources?

Tags: r

I am reading R sources and trying to learn about the Heap Structure. I'm looking for the definition of PROTECT(), but I've founded:

```
$ grep -rn "#define PROTECT(" *
src/include/Rinternals.h:642:#define PROTECT(s) Rf_protect(s)
```

and then

```
$ grep -rn "Rf_protect(" *
src/include/Rinternals.h:803:SEXP Rf_protect(SEXP);
src/include/Rinternals.h:1267:SEXP Rf_protect(SEXP);
```

But I didn't find Rf_protect()'s definition.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Rf_` prefix is a common idiom giving this plain C code the resemblance of a namespace.   So you want to look for `protect(...)` instead:

```
/usr/share/R/include/Rinternals.h:#define protect               Rf_protect
```

And given how 'core' this, you may as well start in `src/main` where a quick `grep -c` leads you to `src/main/memory.c`.  Et voila [on lines 3075 to 3081](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/memory.c#L3075-3081)

```
SEXP protect(SEXP s)
{
    if (R_PPStackTop >= R_PPStackSize)
    R_signal_protect_error();
    R_PPStack[R_PPStackTop++] = CHK(s);
    return s;
}
```

Now that said, you probably want to pay attention to most of the file and not just this function.

Comment: Yes, of course I'm not reading just that function. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I didn't mean that as a put down. You seem to grok how critical `protect()`, I simply wanted to 'cushion' the fact that the function comes up at four lines total ...